# How to Select Each Month of each year Max dated Row

Tags: sql

Please help me out with this select query.

[image]

I need to find 
Exactly like this

[image]

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Finding max date for a Scheduleid in inner query and then using that scheduleid and maxdate to find that particular record which is corresponding to the maximum date using inner join. This will also work in case there are 2 records corresponding to the same maximum date. It will give both the records.

Try this query:-

```
Select a.*
from
your_table_name a
inner join
(
Select Scheduleid, max(ScheduledDate) as max_date
from
your_table_name
group by Scheduleid
) b
on a.Scheduleid=b.Scheduleid and a.ScheduledDate=b.max_date
```

Comment: Working on this

Comment: @MahfuzurRahman If this has helped you, please visit this link http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers